# Issue with Kentico DB changes

Tags: kentico

I have multiple instances of site that share the same database. I've run into an issue where I reverted a page template to its previous version and on the current site instance it looks good, but on other instances it is still uses the old version. I tried restarting the application pools, sites, database server, but it still does not reflect on other instances. I've tried Kentico's System application to restart the application, clear cache and release unused memory, but nothing works. My Kentico version is 12.0.29.

What am I missing, could you please advise on my case?

Answer (score 0):

After reverting template i needed to check-in some changes that CMS made, and after pulling code my sites are the same again. Seems that Kentico saves some changes to files?

Answer (score 0):

Kentico caches very heavily and this is most likely the issue you're seeing.  When you say you have multiple instances, are you talking codebases or what are you talking about?

In the other instances, if you want to see the changes immediately, you need to go to the System app and clear the cache.  This should help you see those changes a lot faster.

Comment: Hi Brenden, this is off-topic to ask something here. But any sample functionality of Map(GIS) which is available in Kentico. Please suggest if you dont' mind

Answer (score 0):

Kentico caches the data heavily as Brenden said. as per my understanding the template versions you need to verify.

If the versions are same you need to go to system module thenrelease the memory and clear the cache of the system.